# DataBinding Snapped Mode Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Using a GridView, I bind to several items in an observable collection. When I enter snapped mode, my GridView fails to load any data and none of the items are clickable. See attached screenshot. My app is on the left and it says featured and favorites. Here is my code:

```
public sealed partial class RestaurantHomePage : MenuFinderWin8.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{
    MenuFinderAppServiceClient serviceClient;
    RestaurantRepository repository;
    Geolocator _geolocator = null;
    ObservableCollection<RestaurantLocation> items;

    public RestaurantHomePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if (!Network.IsNetwork())
        {
            return;
        }
        repository = new RestaurantRepository();
        serviceClient = new MenuFinderAppServiceClient();
        _geolocator = new Geolocator();
        items = new ObservableCollection<RestaurantLocation>();
        //BindData();
    }

    void btnAbout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Flyout f = new Flyout();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(f.HostPopup); // add this to some existing control in your view like the root visual

        // remove the parenting during the Closed event on the Flyout
        f.Closed += (s, a) =>
        {
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(f.HostPopup);
        };

        // Flyout is a ContentControl so set your content within it.
        SupportUserControl userControl = new SupportUserControl();
        userControl.UserControlFrame = this.Frame;
        f.Content = userControl;
        f.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 223, 58, 51));
        f.Width = 200;
        f.Height = 200;
        f.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
        f.PlacementTarget = sender as Button; // this is an UI element (usually the sender)

        f.IsOpen = true;
    }

    void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Flyout f = new Flyout();
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(f.HostPopup); // add this to some existing control in your view like the root visual

        // remove the parenting during the Closed event on the Flyout
        f.Closed += (s, a) =>
        {
            LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(f.HostPopup);
        };

        // Flyout is a ContentControl so set your content within it.
        RestaurantSearchUserControl userControl = new RestaurantSearchUserControl();
        userControl.UserControlFrame = this.Frame;
        f.Content = userControl;
        f.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 223, 58, 51));
        f.Width = 600;
        f.Height = 400;
        f.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
        f.PlacementTarget = sender as Button; // this is an UI element (usually the sender)

        f.IsOpen = true;

    }

    void btnViewFavorites_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.DataMode = Mode.SavedRestaurant;
        if (repository.GetGroupedRestaurantsFromDatabase().Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("You have no saved restaurants.", "No Restaurants");
            messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RestaurantSearchDetails));
        }
    }

    private async void BindData()
    {
        try
        {
            items = await serviceClient.GetSpecialRestaurantsAsync();



            List<RestaurantLocation> myFavs = repository.GetRestaurantLocations();
            foreach (var a in myFavs)
            {
                items.Add(a);
            }

            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = items;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageDialog messsageDialog = new MessageDialog("The MenuFinder service is unavailable at this time or you have lost your internet connection. If your internet is OK, please check back later.", "Unavailable");
            messsageDialog.ShowAsync();
            btnAbout.IsEnabled = false;
            btnSearch.IsEnabled = false;
            btnViewFavorites.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        myBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation.  Any saved state is also
    /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigationParameter">The parameter value passed to
    /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="pageState">A dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
    /// session.  This will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        BindData();
        // TODO: Assign a bindable collection of items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]
    }

    private void itemGridView_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        App.CurrentRestaurantLocation = e.ClickedItem as RestaurantLocation;
        if (App.CurrentRestaurantLocation != null)
        {
            Order order = repository.AddOrder(DateTime.Now, string.Empty, App.CurrentRestaurantLocation.ID);
            App.CurrentOrder = order;
            App.DataMode = Mode.Menu;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RootViewPage));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Click here to see attachment image]

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to snapped view, your gridView hides, and a ListView shows up. You can see this by checking the Visual State Manager that handles going from one to another in your XAML.

So, **Solution is**: adapting the ItemTemplate from your ListView as you did with your GridView by Binding to the proper attributes; you may also want to change the Foreground color of your Font. Also, you want to include the IsItemClickEnabled and ItemClick (or SelectionMode and SelectionChanged) on your ListView.